# How to show differences between rows based on a 'version' column in Oracle data set?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, compare

I have written a variety of SQL queries for a university's large oracle database. The output is a list of available degrees and associated information.

I now need to find a way to show what has changed between versions (based on a column called 'version'. New versions are created when data is changed)

How might I highlight differences based on the output of my selects in the queries?

This is the smallest query I can show as an example:

```
    SELECT
      -- DETAILS
    b.programmeid,
    b.programmecode AS course_udc,
    b.programmeversion AS version,
    b.externalversion AS external_version,
    b.programme AS full_title,
      -- OUTCOMES
    b.programmeoutcomeid AS outcome_number,
    b.outcomedesc AS outcome_description,
    b.programmeoutcometypeid AS graduate_attribute_link
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
              -- DETAILS
    a.programmeid,
    a.programmecode,
    a.programmeversion,
    a.externalversion,
    a.programme,
              -- OUTCOMES
    a.programmeoutcomeid,
    a.outcomedesc,
    a.programmeoutcometypeid
    FROM
    document_application.dmn_domains d,
    (
    SELECT
                      -- DETAILS
    ed.dmn_cuid,
    p.programmeid,
    p.programmecode,
    p.programmeversion,
    p.externalversion,
    p.programme,
                      -- OUTCOMES
    plo.programmeoutcomeid,
    ( dbms_lob.substr(pso.suboutcomedesc,4000,1) ) AS outcomedesc,
    plo.programmeoutcometypeid
    FROM
    document_application.programmes p
    INNER JOIN document_application.edm_entitydomains ed ON p.cuid = ed.entitycuid -- Join with EDM_ENTITYDOMAINS
    INNER JOIN document_application.programmeoutcomes plo ON p.programmeid = plo.programmeid -- Join with PROGRAMMEOUTCOMES
    INNER JOIN document_application.programmesuboutcomes pso ON plo.programmeoutcomeid = pso.suboutcomeid -- Join with PROMGRAMMESUBOUTCOMES
    WHERE
    p.programmecode IN (
    SELECT
    p.programmecode
    FROM
    document_application.programmes p
    GROUP BY
    p.programmecode
    HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
    )
    AND   ed.ett_code = 'P'
    ) a
    WHERE
    a.dmn_cuid = d.cuid
    ) b
    ORDER BY
    course_udc,
    version
```

As you can see, I'll be using a variety of tables.
The b.programmeversion is the version column from which I need to show changes between.

This is an example of the output
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRUbP.png)

Comment: Post sample data and expected resultset.

Comment: With an range of devices such as case expressions which can contains an almost infinite range of highlight possibilities. If you want more details, you have to provide more details first. How about a current query and/or sample data to start with.

Comment: Can you please also post the definition of the table you are looking at?

Comment: I updated with example code. I can add a WHERE clause to select a particular programmeversion if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show what changed between one version and the other, you can use the `MINUS` clause. Say you want to see what changed at the level of columns `c1, c2, c3` between `v1` and `v2`:

- was in version `v1`, but not any more in `v2`

  ```
        select c1, c2, c3 from result_set where VERSION='v1'
  minus select c1, c2, c3 from result_set where VERSION='v2'
  ```
- new in version `v2`, was not in `v1`

  ```
        select c1, c2, c3 from result_set where VERSION='v2'
  minus select c1, c2, c3 from result_set where VERSION='v1'
  ```

hope this helps